# Allow for long user responses on Dialogflow using the phone gateway?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am building an app that is trying to collect feedback from a community using the Dialogflow phone gateway. I want to collect long form user responses and allow the user to just say stop or hang up when they are done (allowing for a few sentences or longer of input). Currently, my message prompts the user and then automatically cuts the user off after one sentence/statement for the next intent. Is there an option to allow for long form dialogue or set up an event timer to allow for longer statements?

The current setup right now:

- Welcome Intent asks the user for comments
- Follow Up Fallback attempt (used to capture the whole piece of dialogue => writes to db)